# horizontal tabs arrow alignment issue

Tags: html, css

I am making horizontal tabs with `onClick` functionality, `onClik` of tabs my corresponding tabs are opening, but I am not getting proper alignment of my pseudo class error, I have added it on my active class.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ABC</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-right:20px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
    animation: fadeEffect 1s;
    border:1px solid #CBCBCB;
}

.tablinks.active:before,
.tablinks.active:after {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border:10px solid transparent;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.tablinks.active:before {
    border-bottom-color: #CBCBCB;
    /*border-bottom-color: #CBCBCB;
    border-right-color: #CBCBCB;*/
}
.tablinks.active:after {
   /* border-left-color: #CBCBCB;*/
}

/* Fade in tabs */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
</style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Tabs Example</h3>

        <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab1')">London</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab2')">Paris</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab3')">Tokyo</button>
        </div>

        <div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
          <h3>London</h3>
          <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
          <h3>Paris</h3>
          <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
        </div>

        <div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
          <h3>Tokyo</h3>
          <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
        </div>
    </div>



    <script>
        function openCity(evt, tabName) {
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting this result:
[image]

I need this kind of result:
[image]

Comment: put the code in snippet!!!

Comment: You might need to wrap your `button` (called tabs) in a wrapper, and put the pointing node as child element inside of it.  This way when a tab/button is clicked, you can display the child element (arrow pointer) which is inside of it.

Comment: [Used a Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/c2zat3dr/)

Answer (score 0):

Just added required CSS and removed some useless things.

Also, Here's the fiddle if you want to play around: https://jsfiddle.net/saurabhsharma/c8ouw8w6/

```js
function openCity(evt, tabName) {
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        }
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-right:20px;
    position: relative;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
    animation: fadeEffect 1s;
    border:1px solid #CBCBCB;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.tablinks.active:before {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border:10px solid transparent;
    vertical-align: middle;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
}
.tablinks.active:before {
    border-bottom-color: #CBCBCB;
    /*border-bottom-color: #CBCBCB;
    border-right-color: #CBCBCB;*/
}

/* Fade in tabs */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <h3>Tabs Example</h3>

        <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab1')">London</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab2')">Paris</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab3')">Tokyo</button>
        </div>

        <div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
          <h3>London</h3>
          <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
          <h3>Paris</h3>
          <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
        </div>

        <div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
          <h3>Tokyo</h3>
          <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove `overflow` from `.tab` and `clearfix` it using `:after` like this

```
.tab {
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.tab:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

set `active button` to `relative` position like this

```
.tab button.active {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
}
```

then, change some css for `:before` and `:after`

```
.tablinks.active:before,
.tablinks.active:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -16px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

set `margin-top` for `tabcontent`

```
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
    animation: fadeEffect 1s;
    border:1px solid #CBCBCB;
    margin-top: 15px; //Added
}
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1sp37hv9/1/)

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. 
There is no obligation to do this. :)

Comment: you get the solution?